# etymology of "a" being used as a prefix to mean "not"

Tags: english, etymology, prefixes

Was merely curious about the origination of "a" being use as a prefix to mean "not", as in atypical or asymptomatic. I have only done a cursory search for an answer, but I figured it may be easier to ask a learned community rather than spend countless hours on my own

Comment: Short answer: Greek

Comment: @Draconis. Slightly longer answer: the prefix a- is productive in English and can be added also to non-Greek words.

Answer (score 3):

From [Ancient Greek ***ἀ-***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80-#Ancient_Greek) from [Proto-Indo-European ***n̥-***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/n%CC%A5-), which is a zero-grade prefix form of [***ne***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/ne), which meant "not".